# Is it possible to create static enum objects in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, enums

I'm working on a streaming-service in JSF (JBoss, Java-EE-Web-Project).

I have a class "Movie" that has a field representing a **list of keywords**.
A Keyword is an **enum** that has a field "name" and an id.

I have a intersection class [MovieKeyword].
This class tells me what keywords are in my movies keywordList. ( Like  [movieID: 5, enum: A] [movieID: 5, enum: B] [movieID: 6, enum: A])

Now I'm wondering: Will JSF create new instances of an keyword for each movie?
Let's say there is a keyword 'action' and there are 500 movies that have 'action' in their keyword list. Will JSF create 500 new Enums or will they share the same object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Enum` is a class and each of the possible values of it are constants, which means they are `static` and `final`. In other words, enums are just instantiated once.

Following quote comes from the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

> An enum type is a type whose fields consist of a fixed set of
>   constants. Common examples include compass directions (values of
>   NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, and WEST) and the days of the week.
>
> Because they are constants, the names of an enum type's fields are in
>   uppercase letters.